# Object renders fine in cycles but disappears in eevee render

Tags: rendering

[image: This is the un-rendered image]
I have been trying to fix this problem . I tried everything . The road has an image texture and I have done some UV un-rapping. It looks fine in cycles render but the road disappears in Eeve render.[image: This is the rendered image.]

Comment: I'd suggest you share your file with us. Go to file > external data > pack all into .blend, thzn go to file > save as, and save a new file with compression enabled in the saving options. The upload the file here and give us the link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I am trying to do the compressing into .blend form but it shows an error that the path to my road image is not found. Can I give you the normal file .

Comment: The image will not appear in rendered form if moved after downloading . It would appesr pink in texture view and checkered in rendered.

Comment: Can you attach your blend file

Comment: Well, hopefully it isn't heavier than the file size upload limit. Try to share your file with its textures packed inside, no matter how.

Answer (score 2):

This was happened to me a while ago and don't know the exact solution but this works for me:

1. Go to *[Output settings-> Post Processing]* and **uncheck compositing**
2. Go to *[output settings-> Output]* and **change the color from 'RGBA' to 'RGB'**

let me know If this works or not.

[image: Settings]

Comment: no man this didn't work either.

Comment: Check blend mode of the road's material. Materials>Settings>Blendmode>make it Opaque.